# Prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $P_1\times\cdots\times P_n.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to prove the following question.

Let $G$ have order $p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_n^{e_n}$ and suppose that $G$ has $n$ Sylow $p$-subgroups $P_1,\cdots,P_n$ where $|P_i|=p_i^{e_i}.$ Prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $P_1\times\cdots\times P_n.$

I think the intersection of those sylow p-subgroups is $\{e\}.$ I don't know what can I do with this question. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: This is not true without more hypotheses. In fact a finite group is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups if and only if it's nilpotent. So the smallest counterexample is $S_3 \cong D_3$, which is the smallest non-nilpotent group.

Comment: The missing condition must be that $G$ has a $\underline{unique}$ $p$-Sylow subgroup for each $p$, or maybe $G$ abelian or as stated by Qiaochu Yuan that $G$ is nilpotent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way the question is phrased, I take it that $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ are the *only* Sylow subgroups of $G$. This means that, for each $i$, $P_i$ is the *only* subgroup of order $p_i^{e_i}$. It follows that each $P_i$ is normal (since $gP_ig^{-1}$ is also a subgroup of order $p_i^{e_i}$). Now prove the following:

**Lemma:** Suppose $H_1,\ldots,H_n$ are normal subgroups of $G$ such that $H_i\cap H_j=\{e\}$ for all $i\neq j$. Then, $$G\cong H_1\times\cdots\times H_n.$$

This amounts to showing that the map $H_1\times\cdots\times H_n\to G$ given by $(h_1,\ldots,h_n)\mapsto h_1\cdots h_n$ is an isomorphism. Start with the case $n=2$ and see what you need to do to generalize.